# What kind of 256 color palette did the Enterprise 64/128 have?

Tags: graphics, video, display, 8-bit-microcomputers, color-display

[The Enterprise 64 or 128 Home Computer apparently had a palette of 256 colors.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_(computer))

However, that is pretty unusual and doesn't fit evenly into the typical 3 channels for RGB. Wikipedia doesn't provide any additional information.

So, were the available bits per channel unevenly assigned and thus not equally represented in the machine's color space?

Or was there an additional intensity channel (RGBI)?

Or did that computer use an entirely different color model than RGB?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Technical Descriptions" link for the Nick Chip on [this Enterprise 64/128 Technical Information page](http://enterprise.iko.hu/technical.htm) is a `.pdf` file. Page 13 of this file seems to say that the 256-color palette uses 3 bits for red, 3 for green, and 2 for blue.

Comment: This BTW aligns pretty well with human colour receiption - which has a bias on green, red, then blue. The interesting thing with the Enterprise's screen is that it can switch resolutions per scanline (without involving the CPU), so there's actually not one mode for the screen, but rather one per scanline.

Comment: @tofro Isn't that pretty normal, except that it normally involves the CPU?

Comment: Isn't that a "standard" 256/8bit (3-3-2) "color palette" of these years? What we need for full answer is what "true" colors (+/- inaccuracy of screens) were assigned to palette, and whether or not palette was programable (cursory read through docs suggests it was).

Comment: palette usually refers to the fixed amount of available colors of a system, all forms of further programmability factored in already. What varies is which of those colors can be shown at the same time, which was a question of memory and bandwidth constraints. A 256 color palette was unusual at that time, common were 16, 64 or 512 colors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monochrome_and_RGB_color_formats

Comment: @user253751 the difference with the Enterprise is that there are no fixed video modes; you establish something like a display program in which you specify the modes you want for the durations you want plus start addresses, and — if memory serves — you're even in charge of scheduling vertical sync. So it's more like there's not one mode for the screen because there's no concept of a fixed mode. Display mode is not a piece of global context, it's always ephemeral.

Comment: @Tommy Well, there actually are modes in the Enterprise: The static homogenuous modes you choose with the BASIC MODE command, this is more a software thing - But as you say, you can program Nick to use a different video mode and setting on any scanline (the standard display driver won't support that fully, but rather only split screens, but the hardware does).

Comment: @tofro So Nick is a bit like Amiga's copper. That could be used to make some interesting demos.

Comment: @snips-n-snails Yes, and it had been used. There's in fact some stunning demos on YouTube for this fascinating computer.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMW4QCaEQJg

Comment: a scene demo showing off the typical effects, seems the machine could handle them well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9G-_faHZhg